# SEO URLs in custom module

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, seo

I have a module built in magento 2.1.16 which store details of contacts in database and fetches them on list page and details view page.
The contacts are of 3 types

1. Branches (https://roadmaster.com.co/en_sa/contacts)
2. Dealers (https://roadmaster.com.co/en_sa/dealers)
3. Authorized Centers (https://roadmaster.com.co/en_sa/servicecenters)

When i clik on more information on any I get url like this one https://roadmaster.com.co/en_sa/dealers/view/index/id/24/
While i want something like 
https://roadmaster.com.co/en_sa/dealers/al-khaleej

or for this url 
https://roadmaster.com.co/en_sa/contacts/view/index/id/1/
I want something like
https://roadmaster.com.co/en_sa/contacts/rm-jeddah

The contacts are stored in single table and are distinguished by contact_type attribute.

Comment: Hi Check this out it may be help you for your problem   https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191828/magento-2-custom-module-rewrite-url

Answer (score 0):

**Do below steps**
[image: Go to Url Rewrite from marketing menu]

**Now add url rewrite**

[image: Click on add url rewrite button]

**Now do as below and save it.**

[image: Set User Freindly Url]

*By this process you will get user freindly url as you want.*

*Thanks.*

Comment: Thank you but i don't want this to do manually. I want it automatically (based on url-key) like magento has it for products and categories.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do everything manually under *Marketing -> Url Rewrites*

Then you should do something like:

1. In Module that process /contacts/view/index/id/1/ add new field(attribute) for new seo friendly url, like magento do this for ex. CMS Pages [image]
2. When you save this entity, pick up data from the field created in [Step 1] and create record in url rewrite table programmatically.